Error reading MariaDB database in Access with ODBC connection
For context: the IT department decided that we have to switch our Office 365 suite from x32 to x64. We have some legacy Access applications that we need to test in x64.
In Access I need to make a connection to a Maria DB database. I'm using an ODBC 64-bit connector (MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver). If I import the tables locally, I have no problems. But when I try to make a Linked table, I get an ODBC error "ODBC: call failed".
I have been searching high and low. I've started Tracing the ODBC-connection the find the error, but no results yet.
Did anyone encounter a similar problem?
Worth noting: even when I add the ODBC connection to a new Access database, I encounter the same problem.
Thanks!

If you use mariadb, then why don't you use its own odbc driver, as opposed to using mysql's driver?

I have found the solution here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=114872
A workaround is to disable SSPS via the connection option NO_SSPS=1 or checking the appropriate box in the GUI (Details >> Misc >> [X] Prepare Statements on the client)

[12 Sep 6:41] Bogdan Degtyariov Dear everyone,
please note that MariaDB Server and MySQL Server are not always
compatible on a protocol level. For that reason you cannot use MySQL
ODBC driver with MariaDB.
I see this error in the ODBC trace file:
"[MySQL][ODBC 9.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.11.6-MariaDB-0+deb12u1]No
data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"
As already mentioned, due to protocol incompatibility (which by the
way was introduced around version 8.4) it is expected that MySQL ODBC
Driver 8.4/9.0 fails to do certain operations on MariaDB server.
The issue is around server-side prepared statement (SSPS) being
executed. MySQL network protocol and C API for Prepared Statements are
using a new function mysql_stmt_bind_named_param() instead of
mysql_stmt_bind_param().
A workaround is to disable SSPS via the connection option NO_SSPS=1 or
checking the appropriate box in the GUI (Details >> Misc >> [X]
Prepare Statements on the client)
We will only accept this as a bug if there is a proven issue between
GA versions of MySQL Server and MySQL ODBC driver.


Again, why don't you use mariadb odbc driver with mariadb? If you check the comment on the same bug page by the same author, it reads: Just to make it clear: we do not recommend using the NO_SSPS workaround as a means of work with the data on production servers. Just a quick hack to prove the concept, which is neither reliable nor documented. For MariaDB Server the appropriate ODBC Driver from MariaDB should be used. There could be more incompatibilities that we are not aware. Also, we do not guarantee and do not test that MySQL ODBC driver works against Maria DB Server.

Yes I know, but the IT department is very difficult about installing just about anything new.. so using the one connector they accept is easier..

I think if you made the point to IT that mysql driver is not guaranteed to work with mariadb, then they will be more keen to get it replaced. Having this discussion is really your call. However, your hack really should not be a recommended approach in SO.
